# MPMoviePlayerController Freezes

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, movie

So, I'm having a really bizarre issue with MPMoviePlayerController.

I've added an MPMoviePlayerController to my view using the following:

```
self.moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"finished" ofType:@"mp4"]]];
[self.moviePlayer.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 640)];
[self.moviePlayer prepareToPlay];
self.moviePlayer.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeFill;
self.moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;
self.moviePlayer.fullscreen = YES;
self.moviePlayer.backgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
self.moviePlayer.repeatMode = MPMovieRepeatModeOne;
[self.moviePlayer prepareToPlay];
[self.movieView addSubview:self.moviePlayer.view];
```

However, after a certain amount of time the app freezes: I can't scroll, can't interact with any UI elements, nothing. The app just doesn't respond. I know it's the MPMoviePlayerController as the app works fine without it. The video is only 12 seconds long.

It freezes the app even after the view with the MoviePlayer isn't in view. I've dealloc'd it, set it to nil and stopped it from playing, however it still freezes the app even after it has disappeared.

```
- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated {

NSLog(@"view disappeared");

[self.moviePlayer stop];
[self setMoviePlayer:nil];
self.moviePlayer.repeatMode = MPMovieRepeatModeNone;
[self.moviePlayer dealloc];
[self.moviePlayer release];
```

}

Comment: Is it safe to call "prepareToPlay" twice?

Comment: is your movieView is scrollview ?? if you want to see the video with full screen then you can directly add video to window. your code is proper.

Comment: It's not a scroll view.